# (search) event in ion-search-bar don't trigger when press enter in android keyboard

Tags: android, ionic4

```
<ion-searchbar #search animated placeholder="Search" cancelButtonText="Cancel" inputmode="search" (search)="handler_search($event.target.value)"></ion-searchbar>
```

In IOS keyboard (seach) event will trigger when press enter, but not in android keyword.
How i fix that?

Comment: What is browser version? it work on chrome ^77

Answer (score 0):

```
<ion-searchbar #search animated placeholder="Search" cancelButtonText="Cancel" inputmode="search"(keypress)="onKeyPressed($event)"></ion-searchbar>
    
    onKeyPressed(event: any) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
console.log(event.target.value);
          // Call function
        }
      }
```